# What does C(n - 1, 2) edges mean in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

My graph theory book postulates the if a simple graph with n vertices has at least `C(n - 1, 2) + 2` edges then the graph must be Hamiltonian.

This is probably true but I am confused by the notation of what `C(n - 1, 2)` means?

C usually represents a cycle but clearly not in this case. And whatever function they are referencing takes 2 parameters which is quite strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the binomial coefficient $n-1$ choose $2$, i.e.
$$\binom{n-1}{2},$$
which is
$$\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}.$$
In general, $C(n,k)$ is alternative notation used for the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$, which is defined by
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$$

Comment: Ah thank you! That makes sense! I was trying to work out some graph theory concept and it was just a simple C operation haha